# Node running many POST requests at once

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to make a bunch of post requests at once from my node.js script I have the same payload for every one of the requests and would want to simply spin them all off at once in some kind of loop and then make them write to a DB upon completion.
Sample Code to demonstrate the logic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    makePostRequest(updateDB);
}

function makePostRequest (callback) {
    http.post("test", function (result) {callback(result)});
}

function updateDB(result) {
    db.put({result: result});
}
```

The question is, is it better to do this using multithreading or does the fact that node will run these post request asynchronously take care of it and result in the same performance? In other words, will these post requests all happen asynchronously in a same way you would expect a multhreaded program behave and result in the same performance?

My goal is to minimize execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the improvement in execution time you'll see from multi-threading through child processes here will be minimal.  As you said, the request are already executed asynchronously.

In fact, you may see a decrease in performance as `n`, the number of concurrent requests, increases.

To be sure, you could run a benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you send 10 requests in parallel. I think that this number is small and will not cause a problem.

There are some things that you have to pay attention to.

- There is a maximum of concurrent outgoing connections for your server
- How many concurrent requests is the remote server able to serve without slowing down?
- If you launch the requests with a for loop, the for loop runs to completion before the requests are effectively sent out.

If you have to launch a really big number of requests, they will be faster completed, if you limit the maximal number of concurrent requests. Also think about about throttling the launch, by using `setTimeout` between calls to `makePostRequest`.

I don't know what are the thresholds where you need to take these precautions.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the logic that I described earlier in the question. Reasoning being is that node runs its async calls separately on a different thread so that its not blocking the main thread. his means that running POST async will behave similarly to what I wanted from multithreading